# Erlang list vs tuple comparison

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

Assume that there is an erlang list of lists:

Note that the size of the lists are fixed. In this case 3.

```
A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,8,3],[1,9,3]]
```

I am trying to write function which will drop all the elements which are of the form `[1,_,3]`.
So my expected output would be of the form: `[[4,5,6]]`

One solution which I could think about was the lists:`dropwhile()` function which can be used.

I am having trouble constructing the predicate function. Is it easier to convert every element into a tuple and then do the comparison? If so, there is no proper way I could omit the middle element.

Can you please help me arrive at the solution? Any other efficient approach would also be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: 
Question Extenstion:

Assume two erlang list of lists:

A = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [4,5,6]]

B = [[1,4,3], [4,7,6], [7,8,9], [4,9,7], ]

The output F(A,B) = [[7,8,9], [4,9,7]]

F is defined to be a function, which removes from list B all the elements which are matching any one of the elements in list A in the first and the third position.

In this case, all those elements in list B which are matching [1, _ ,3] or [2, _ , 4] or [4 , _ , 6] are deleted from the list to give the resulting list.

I am struggling to write F.

Comment: What does your predicate function look like so far?  I think you'll find it would be quite similar for tuples or lists.

Comment: My best effort so far has been,

lists:filter(fun(X) -> {1,_,3} == erlang:list_to_tuple(X) end,A).

But I am getting a _ unbound variable error. The single equal to (=) only assigns to the variable if its false and does not return true or false.

Answer (score 12):

Your filter function needs some help:

```
lists:filter(fun([1, _, 3]) -> false; (_) -> true end,
             [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,8,3],[1,9,3]]).
```

You need the match in the function head to make this work.

---

As for having multiple filters, you can use a map of funs (not tested):

```
composed_filter(Tests, Input) ->
  lists:filter(fun(X) -> lists:all([F(X) || F <- Tests]) end,
               Input).
```

---

For using multiple filters, you can do:

```
filter(fun([1,_,3]) -> true;
          ([5,_,7]) -> true;
          ([9,_,13]) -> true;
          (_) -> false end, Input)
% or
composed_filter([fun([1,_,3]) -> true; (_) -> false end,
                 fun([5,_,7]) -> true; (_) -> false end,
                 fun([9,_,13]) -> true; (_) -> false end],
                Input)
```

Though unless you need a *programmable dynamic* composability, you should probably just use the first. Another way, again is to run the composition with a function rather than having a specialized composed_filter. This is a more combinator-style approach which the Haskell crowd would love. Note that the above functions are slightly different. The first has `orelse` semantics whereas the latter has `andalso` semantics. That is in the first case, you get the element if one or more of the patterns match, whereas in the latter case, you only get a result if *all* the patterns/funs match. You could use `lists:any/2` to obtain a `composed_any_filter`.

Comment: Is it possible to have two predicates in the same filter function? In that case, the function header would be a mess right? 
The only way I could think was to make the list pass through two sequential filters as defined above. But I guess this would not make it scale to have any new additional predicates...

Comment: Added to the answer with one solution. There are more such solutions including walking the list twice. This may incur an overhead though depending on the list you are trying to walk.

Comment: That is an elegant solution. But how are we gonna have a list of functions. Assume for the same problem defined in the question, if we want to compare for not just [1,_,3].. but also for [1,_,5],[7,_9] and so on. At that time writing all of them in one filter is advisable?

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I should probably be trying other methods, but my question has a slight extension and it would be great if you can throw some light on it.

Comment: Come again if my edits does not make it clear. I am not sure I understand what you are looking for?

Comment: I have extended the question to bring in the bigger picture. Please let me know if I may need to come on chat in case these comments are cumbersome.

Answer (score 3):

`dropWhile` can only return a prefix of the list, so it's not going to work. Use `filter` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I finally understood the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to come up with a solution for the extended question:

Given A and B as in question:

```
F(A,B) ->
    lists:filter(fun(X) -> predicate(X,B) end, A).

predicate(X, B) ->
    Xr = lists:delete(lists:nth(2,X),X),
    Br = lists:map(lists:delete(lists:nth(2,Y),Y),B),
    lists:member(Xr, Br).
```

This lists library is so cool.. :)